# Why, when i create a csv file in python, between rows appears empty row?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, export-to-csv

I tried to create a csv file with content numbering titles and prices through Python.

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w') as file:
    csv_names = csv.writer(file)
    csv_names.writerow(['Num','Name','Price'])
    csv_names.writerow([1,'Trace',3200])
    csv_names.writerow([2,'Susie',4000])
    csv_names.writerow([3,'Lance',4400])
```

When creating a file and content, I got the expected result, but after each row I got an empty line:

```
Num,Name,Price

1,Trace,3200

2,Susie,4000

3,Lance,4400
```

Actually i think there's nothing wrong with this but, when print out each row printed out exactly like on top:

```
with open('names.csv', 'r') as file:
    for row in file:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Try using the `newline=""` keyword argument when opening the file. This is generally recommended when using the `csv` module.